# I'm having troubles using pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I have a simple python script (meant to be run in terminal) that I want to compile, or at least make executable for PCs without python installed, so when I make an EXE with `pyinstaller --onefile --nowindow random.py` and send it over to my friend his windows defender stops it and even after getting around it at the `list = open(fileName,'w+')` it crashes. I have no idea why because it runs perfectly using `python random.py`
Here's the code:

```
import glob
import os
import random

a = True
while a == True:
    x = input('Do you want to make a new savefile? (y/n): ')
    if x == 'y':
        fileName = input('\nWhat do you want its name to be? (put .txt at the end)\n')
        list = open(fileName, 'w+')
        addToList = True
        a = False
    elif x == 'n':
        svfs = glob.glob("*.txt")
        print('\nWhich save file do you want to use?\n', svfs)
        fileName = input()
        a = False
    else:
        print('Please give a valid answer (\"y\" for yes, \"n\" for no)')

if x == 'n':
    print('\nDo you want to overwrite the selected savefile?')
    if os.path.getsize(str(fileName)) == 0:
        print('(The savefile is empty)')
    else:
        print('(The savefile isn\'t empty)')
    b = input('(y/n): ')
    if b == 'y':
        list = open(fileName, 'w')
        addToList = True
    elif b == 'n':
        addToList = False
    else:
        print('Please give a valid answer (\"y\" for yes, \"n\" for no)')

if addToList == True:
    print("\nAdd items to the list:\n(type !done when you're done)")
    while addToList == True:
        string = input("\t")
        if string == "!done":
            addToList = False
        else:
            list.writelines([string, '; '])
    list.close()

print(random.choice(open(str(fileName), 'r').readline().split('; ')))
input()
```

Comment: You can't call this "random.py".  That will cause a circular import when you do `import random`.  Also note you don't need to escape double-quotes inside a single-quoted string, and you never need to call `str()` on something that's already a string.

Comment: You aren't changing directories.  If this gets downloaded into a protected directory, then `open(xxx,'w')` is going to fail.

Comment: @TimRoberts what do you suggest i should do?

Comment: First, call the file something other than `random.py`.  Next, you'll need to know where these "save files" are stored.  You'll want to `os.chdir` to that folder, or at least have the location stored somewhere.